# ComboBox value determines what to do with associated sheet

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I previously did some work (poorly coded, but hey, it runs) using CheckBox true/false which looked like this:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        wb.sheets("PQC 1001").Delete
    Else: CheckBox1.Value = True
    End If
```

This code works; I have each of the 25 CheckBoxes assigned to each of the 25 sheets.  The improvement I'm trying to make is to move from CheckBoxes to ComboBoxes.

With ComboBoxes, I should be able to allow people to select between values of 0, 1, 2, or 3, to indicate the number of each sheet they want.  I initialize the userform to do this:

```
ComboBox1.List = Array("0", "1", "2", "3")
```

What I'm having trouble with is assigning each value to a process.  So far I have:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "0" Then
    wb.sheets("PQC 1001").Delete
    Else: ComboBox1.Value = "1"
```

I can't make an "else then" for multiple entries and do not know what else I could do to make this work.  My thoughts/plans are to list (This gives errors about the "end if"):

```
Dim wb As Workbook

If ComboBox1.Value = "0" Then
wb.sheets("PQC 1001").Delete

If ComboBox1.Value = "2" Then
wb.sheets("PQC 1001").Copy ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheets.Count)

If ComboBox1.Value = "3" Then
wb.sheets("PQC 1001").Copy ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheets.Count)
wb.sheets("PQC 1001").Copy ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheets.Count)

Else: ComboBox1.Value = "1"

End If
```

Any thoughts on how I can make this work would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I didn't know about ElseIf.

My working code looks like this:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "0" Then
    sheets("PQC 1001").Delete

ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "2" Then
    sheets("PQC 1001").Copy After:=sheets(2)

ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "3" Then
    sheets("QC 1001").Copy After:=sheets(2)
    sheets("QC 1001").Copy After:=sheets(2)

Else: ComboBox1.Value = "1"

End If
```

Sorry for posting something I should have been able to find.  Hopefully this helps others if they have a similar question!

Comment: You might also look into `Select Case` since you have 25 of these.

Comment: I'll need to read up on Select Case to know what it does.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Looked into it; much, much cleaner to write/read.  It doesn't appear to do anything to the speed (25 items, not 2M items), but yes, I'm quite glad you made me aware of that funcation!  Thanks Portland Runner. +1'd